# Does this allow conclusions about an interaction in a linear mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, model, linear

I am analysing an experiment where groups received either one type of verum treatment (there are two different types of verum treatment) or a placebo treatment. I want to find out whether the different verum treatment types have an impact on test scores over time (compared to placebo) and have a special interest in whether the participant's sex has an influence. Scores are measured 6 times over several days.

So I have 6 groups defined by sex and treatment (with t being the verum treatment, p being placebo):

female, p
female, t1
female, t2
male, p
male, t1
male, t2

My initial mixed model looked like this: 
score ~ session * sex * treatment
It presents several problems that I am considering to circumvent.

That is why I am thinking about creating a new factor "fac" derived from sex and treatment to use in my mixed model, which would look like this: 
score ~ fac * session

female_p
female_t1
female_t2
male_p
male_t1
male_t2

With the new factor "fac" derived from sex and treatment in place instead of sex and treatment themselves, would my model still allow conclusions about an interaction that tells me whether sex in relation to treatment has an impact over time?

Comment: What are the problems that you are trying to prevent and why do you think your model will do so?

Comment: What you describe with the 2nd model sounds like a simple reparameterisation of the first model so it is unlikely to solve whatever problem you had with the first, but since you don't say what the problem is, it is impossible to say much more. Also, what is `session` ? Is this the time variable denoting the 6 measurement occasions ?